# Getting this localhost:8080 prompt window on every new page or redirection

Tags: google-chrome, url, localhost, authorization, port

I am getting this weird prompt window from yesterday since restarting my laptop on every redirection of url or whenever I open the new tab it just pops up. Going to localhost:8080 show unauthorized. Secondly in my developers option I have started seeing following 2 errors

1 `content.static.js:20 GET http://localhost:8080/contentDocumentStart.js 401 (Unauthorized)`

2 `GET https://dw4sx0xk0hu8c.cloudfront.net/contentDocumentStart.js 403`

Kindly if anyone can help. I have searched, came across few of the tomcat solution but I don't know what is the issue or how to sign in (more importantly whats it requiring it for).

[image: localhost:8080 Prompt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason I tried updating chrome and restarting it several times but in vain. The thing that worked is I restarted my PC (for some new software changes to take effect). And while browsing I noticed I wasn't getting the pop up window any more on chrome. So if it happens with someone, try restarting the PC.